# Serilogs not working in linux server in aspnet core 2.1

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm creating dotnet core 2.1 project.I used serilogs.In my windows machine it's working fine.But after hosted it,serilogs not working.Not creating logs folder and log file.I hosted it in ubuntu 18.04 version server.
I tried it by creating logs folder manually and gave it to read write permissions

```
   sudo chmod 775 /var/app/logs
   sudo chown www-data /var/app/logs
```

here is the code in program class

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"logs\log-{Date}.log", fileSizeLimitBytes: null, retainedFileCountLimit: null)
            .CreateLogger();
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
                 {
                     builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
                     builder.AddFilter("ApiServer", LogLevel.Debug);
                     builder.AddSerilog();
                 })
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

here is my startup class code

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(s => s.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning)));
        services.AddMvc()
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                    .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    });
       services.AddCors();
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddTransient<Seed>();
        services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IDatingRepository, DatingRepository>();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                  .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
        services.AddScoped<LogUserActivity>();



        IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

        });

        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();



        // services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        //     options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        //     options.AddPolicy("SuperAdminPhotoRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("SuperAdmin"));
        // });


        // services.AddCors();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Seed seeder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {

            app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                    }
                });
            });

            // app.UseHsts();
        }

        // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        seeder.SeedUsers();
        //  app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Fallback", action = "Index" }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

here is the way I used logs

```
public class PhotosController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<PhotosController> _logger;

    public PhotosController(ILogger<PhotosController> logger
    )
    {
        _logger = logger;

    }

     [HttpPost("{id}/setMain")]
      public async Task<IActionResult> SetMainPhoto(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
             _logger.LogDebug("Starting to change main photo");  
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
     _logger.LogError("An error occurs while changing photo");
      }}}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.this is working fine in windows machine.Only this happened after hosting

Comment: can you try to write your logs under /tmp/ to see if it is permission issue or not?

Comment: You're using the backslash als path separator. It should be a forward slash on Linux. Not sure if this is the real issue. S.a. Path.PathSeparator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.pathseparator?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Simonare,Thanks alot for your comment
In this system,contains a photos upload feature,when uploading a photo also happened this problem,that time I changed user permissions.after that can upload photos
same thing did for serilogs.but it's not creating log file

Comment: @Christoph, thanks alot for your reply
I changed the backslash to forward slash,but same thing happening

Comment: anyone please help me......

Comment: Did you found the problem ? I get the same issu

Comment: no it's still not working, now I'm not doing it

Comment: @DevAra Did you find a solution ?

Comment: no I have ignored that

Answer (score 1):

In your `Program.cs` file you need

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog();
```

the important part is `.UseSerilog()`

Comment: I have already added it like builder.AddSerilog();
but not working. anyway thanks for the reply